# Trying to authenticate to grafana with http api

Tags: grafana, http-authentication

I'm trying to make an http request with my web app but I see unauthorized response. If I use curl in command line I see a response: curl http://api_key:KEY@MyGrafana:3000/api/org. My problem is that when I try to access grafana using the same url in the browser I'm getting unauthorized. Any idea why is happening this?

Comment: Do you use curl from same client machine ? Does it work always  with curl ? and never on browser ?

Comment: yes I'm using curl in the same client machine. Always work with curl and never with the browser. Thanks @TechFree

Comment: If I get in with my user name and password then it works in the browser...

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No I didn`t :'(